# Getting permission denied in Java when reading a file (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, file, permissions, permission-denied

Hello Everyone i recently moved to **Ubuntu** to work on a project.
I have to simply read from a file, using:

`File root = new File(fileroot); 
 File sourceFile = new File(root,filename);`

But when i run the application, i get:
`error: error reading FilePath; FilePath (Permession denied).`

(FilePath is the path where the file is located, i've hidden it for privacy purposes)

I guess is something due to the Operative System, because running the same code on Windows doesn't give me any error. Is there a way to solve this? I mean a way to get those permissions directly from Java or maybe changing them from terminal using commands?

Thanks in advance for your answer guys!

Comment: You can run the program as an user that has permission to open that file. Example `sudo java -jar myProg.jar`.

Comment: the other thing to look into is how those files are **created**. You see, there is not much sense in first **creating** files without read permissions, forcing you to add them later on. So, you could be looking into the **umask** setting on your system; it seems rather strange that you are dealing with files that are not **readable** in the first place. So, yes, the answers help you to **fix** that problem; but you should rather be asking (and fixing) the "why you got there" in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the message says, you probably don't have permissions to read that file. To troubleshoot, you can add:

```
System.out.println(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

to find the exact location of the file that you're trying to read and then checking the file system permissions for it:

```
ls -la <path to your file>
```

Verify that you have the `r` permission, otherwise this is the error that you get.

Comment: I get: ` -rw------- 1 root root 2044 ott  3 18:00 PATHTOTHEFILE` 

I guess i have Read and Write permission right?

Comment: What that means is that only the user `root` can read it. To fix it, you have to either change the ownership of the file to you via `chown <your user> RaggruppatoreLibriPe‌​rAutore.java` or add read permissions: `chmod a+r RaggruppatoreLibriPe‌​rAutore.java`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to navigate to the file and change the permission to allow every user to read the file.
The easiest is via terminal:

`chmod +r /path/to/file`

To see all the different uses follow the link and learn about chmod.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: I managed to do something with this answer, now that error is gone, but i got another one on another file. How about extending the permission to the entire folder?

Comment: you can use the recursive parameter "-R" with chmod (like with most linux commands". You'd do this as such:
`chmod +r -R /path/to/directory/` Be very careful that you select the correct path. If you do this to the root directory you allow permission on your whole system to every user. This would be atrocious for data security